# Looking for a term describing the act of learning something while doing something else

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title suggests I am looking for a term used by a teacher I once had. It describes unintentionally learning something new whilst actually researching or simply learning about something different.

Comment: there is an idiom "learning by osmosis" (you can google it, but here is one of many hits http://www.languagetutoring.co.uk/learningthroughosmosis.html  However the term is most frequently used not so much 'by doing something else" but instead, when exposed to the topic you're learning without necessarily making a concerted effort to learn it.

Comment: [Ancillary learning](http://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=H8B&biw=1920&bih=941&q="ancillary+learning") brings up many results.

Comment: Could the teacher have used the term meta-learning?  For example, learning social skills, or learning how to organize a task, while being taught something else?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there are several terms in use for this:

> ***incidental learning***, ***random learning***

Source, further reading: [EduTech Wiki](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Incidental_learning).